# Vuex createNamespacedHelpers is not working

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuex

I'm building a Vuex store with multiple modules.
I want to easily define and map the types of the getters and the actions so that I can have automatic module name in the path instead calling $store.getters["modulename/gettername"] for all the methods.

I found that I can use createNamespacedHelpers helper from vuex library but it's not working or something is missing in my configuration.

Here is the namespace-helper.js file I have

```
import { createNamespacedHelpers } from 'vuex';
import { getters, actions } from './types';

const { mapGetters, mapActions } = createNamespacedHelpers('modulename');

export default {
  computed: mapGetters([
    getters.getMethod1,
    getters.getMethod2
  ]),
  methods: mapActions([
    actions.actionMethod1,
    actions.actionMethod2
  ])
}
```

In my vue.js I have

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import store from './store/index';
import someModuleNameSpaceHelper from './store/modules/someModule/namespace-helper';

Vue.use(Vuex);

window.vueRoot = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-root',
  store,
  someModuleNameSpaceHelper ,
  computed: {

  }
});
```

I thought at this point I would have access to vuex getters like: vueRoot.getMethod1

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an [object property value shorthand](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_oop-besides-classes.html#_property-value-shorthands-1), so your code snippet

```
window.vueRoot = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-root',
  store,
  someModuleNameSpaceHelper ,
  computed: {

  }
});
```

is equivalent to

```
window.vueRoot = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-root',
  store,
  someModuleNameSpaceHelper: someModuleNameSpaceHelper,
  computed: {

  }
});
```

which is like doing

```
window.vueRoot = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-root',
  store,
  someModuleNameSpaceHelper: {
    computed: {...}, // vue won't see this
    methods: {...}   // vue won't see this
  } ,
  computed: {

  }
});
```

How about changing it to

```
window.vueRoot = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-root',
  store,
  computed: someModuleNameSpaceHelper.computed,
  methods: someModuleNameSpaceHelper.methods
});
```

Comment: Thank you. with your comment I foud that the '...' thing is actually a spread operator and not a placeholder for "other stuff" in the declaration. Also I've updated Visual studio code and now it's not seeing it as an error.